# Prevent users to input the number 0 in my add to cart

Tags: php

What to add in my query to prevent users from adding number 0 from the input , because if you input 0 it accepts it and still goes thru the cart

This is my code

```
<?php
include('session.php');
if(isset($_POST['cart'])){
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $qty=$_POST['qty'];

    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select product_qty from product where productid='$id'");
$result=mysqli_fetch_object($query);
if($result->product_qty < $qty){
   echo 'Input must be lower than the stocks';
} else{
        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from cart where productid='$id' and userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
            echo "Product already on your cart!";
        }
        else{
            mysqli_query($conn,"insert into cart (userid, productid, qty) values ('".$_SESSION['id']."', '$id', '$qty')");
        }
  }
}
```

[Picture of the system with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRJIo.jpg)
THANK YOU VERY MUCH.

Comment: Check if `$qty > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    include('session.php');
if(isset($_POST['cart'])){
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $qty=$_POST['qty'];
if($qty>0){//This Condition work for you
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select product_qty from product where productid='$id'");
$result=mysqli_fetch_object($query);
if($result->product_qty < $qty){
   echo 'Input must be lower than the stocks';
} else{
        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from cart where productid='$id' and userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
            echo "Product already on your cart!";
        }
        else{
            mysqli_query($conn,"insert into cart (userid, productid, qty) values ('".$_SESSION['id']."', '$id', '$qty')");
        }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to echo that 0 is an invalid number? tried echo adding  (echo '0 is an invalid Input'; ) but nothing comes out. Thanks

Comment: try `echo "0";` not `echo 0;`

Answer (score 0):

I would just change this

```
include('session.php');
if(isset($_POST['cart']) && !empty($_POST['qty'])){
   $id=$_POST['id'];
   $qty=$_POST['qty'];
....
```

In PHP `empty` sees `0` as being empty,  so `&& !empty(0) = false`  Which fails the whole if condition, and nothing inside it runs.

If you want to output an error message then do it this way

```
 if(isset($_POST['cart'])){
   if(!empty($_POST['qty'])){
      //if we are bailing on empty no need to do any of this
      $id=$_POST['id'];
      $qty=$_POST['qty'];
      .... other stuff ....
   }else{
      //if it's not !empty then it must be empty.
      echo "Please enter a quantity";
   }
}
```

P.S the benefit of empty, is that this is also empty `''`.  The only thing I would add is maybe a `trim()` which would prevent `'   '`, but if you are only allowing `#` then should be ok, for the most part.

A wise man once told me many moons ago, to start every form validation error with `Please` that way you are not setting a tone that blames the end-user.  I thought he was full of it, but I did it anyway ... lol

I saw your comment

> is there a way to echo that 0 is an invalid number

Sure but what does that mean, if I'm filling this out and it says that.  What does that mean to me? if it says "Please enter a quantity" well that's pretty clear.

Comment: where would i put the query, tried doing " 0 " but it doubles the echo , it echoes both ( "0" and "input must be lower than the stocks")

Comment: what's this `where would i put the insert button`,  and this, `input must be lower than the stocks` what I posted...never reaches that.  Why would you check if there is more stock .. when they request `0qty` of the stock.

Comment: its ok now haha , i wont put an echo , thank you very much sir

Comment: sure, it was no problem.  I put an echo, just one that is descriptive.